# how to join two tables and using lookup function together in r

Tags: r

i have two table (D1 and D2)

```
D1

site  dmax 
A     20
B     30
C     40

D2

site  velocity
A      120
A      130
A      130
B      140
B      140
C      134
C      124
C      152
```

My requirement is a third table `D3` with column site, velocity and dmax together
e.g.

```
site  velocity dmax
A      120     20
A      130     20
A      130     20
B      140     30
B      140     30
C      134     40
C      124     40
C      152     40
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `merge`

```
> merge(D2, D1)
  site velocity dmax
1    A      120   20
2    A      130   20
3    A      130   20
4    B      140   30
5    B      140   30
6    C      134   40
7    C      124   40
8    C      152   40
```

Comment: actually i want to add dmax in table D2. for that which i think lookup can be used. but i dont know how to use that and update table D2